# wordpress - setup subscription plan on website with stripe?

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

What are the requirements and steps on creating a subscription form. I created subcription plan in stripe dashboard,I have stripe.js in my website. What will be the next? any referrence please.I want my form like this https://wpcurve.com/signup/

thanks in advance

Comment: Stripe has some amazing documentation. It looks like you haven't bothered to read any of it.

Comment: but i dont get it :(

Comment: So you want someone on Stack Overflow to write it for you? Sounds like you need to hire a web developer.

Comment: no i just want to know what will i do next?

Comment: As I've said, read and digest the documentation, or contact Stripe Support... I mean, they have even published a full tutorial on creating your first subscription: https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/subscriptions

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you wouldn't go with a WordPress plugin? Even the commercial version of https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-full-stripe-free/ will cost way less than trying to develop yourself

If you still want to build it yourself, [this is the most detailed](https://pippinsplugins.com/series/integrating-stripe-com-with-wordpress/) WordPress Stripe Plugin I've come across.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Our company has adopted the recurring model with Paypal. Stripe appears to be the better solution. Oddly enough, it appears that Stripe is a more thorough SaaS platform. They've figured this thing out. If you check out the [Stripe: Building a Subscription Form](https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/subscription-signup) page, their api integrates with that.

I know this may be an old post. My reason for contributing to this thread is "just in case" another burgeoning developer is looking for an answer. Hopefully this'll help lead the way to finding a solution.